# A sufficient condition for a unitary ring to be a local ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, local-rings

> **Theorem.** Let $R$ be a unitary ring such that $R$ is a subring of a division ring $D$. If for all $d(\ne 0)\in D$ either $d\in R$ or $d^{-1}\in R$ then $R$ is a local ring.
>
> *My Proof.* It suffices to prove that $R\setminus U(R)$ is an ideal of $R$ where $U(R)$ denotes the set of all units of $R$. For this we first show that if $x\in R\setminus U(R)$ then $Rx\subseteq R\setminus U(R)$. So let $x\in R\setminus U(R)$. Clearly then $x\ne 0$.
>
> Suppose that there exists $r\in R$ such that $rx\in U(R)$. Consequently, since $D$ is a division ring, we have $x\in U(R)$, a contradiction. So $Rx\subseteq R\setminus U(R)$ for all $x\in R\setminus U(R)$.
>
> Let $x,y\in R\setminus U(R)$. Let $x^{-1},y^{-1}$ denote the inverses of $x$ and $y$ respectively in $D$ (clearly both $x$ and $y$ are non-zero so that they are invertible in $D$). Then note that by hypothesis $xy^{-1}\in R$ or $yx^{-1}\in R$. Since $1\in R$ it follows that either $1+xy^{-1}\in R$ or $1+yx^{-1}\in R$. In the former case, $$(1+xy^{-1})y\in R\setminus U(R)\Rightarrow y+x\in R\setminus U(R)$$ and in the later, $$(1+yx^{-1})x\in R\setminus U(R)\Rightarrow x+y\in R\setminus U(R)$$So we are done.

**Question**

Is my argument correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small gap like "Let $x,y\in R\setminus U(R)$... clearly $x,y$ are nonzero..." but of course, they *could* be zero, and may not have inverses.  But of course that's rectified easily enough since in any such case $x+y$ is obviously a nonunit of $R$.

Otherwise the idea is sound.

But look at this:

> Then note that by hypothesis $xy^{-1}\in R$ or $yx^{-1}\in R$.

This observation is actually the key to a very short solution.  Let $x,y$ actually be arbitrary nonzero elements of $R$.  Then (by what you said) either $Rx\subseteq Ry$ or $Ry\subseteq Rx$.

In other words, the principal left ideals are totally ordered.

Then it is a simple exercise to show *the entire collection of left ideals is totally ordered*.

Thus any maximal left ideal would have to be unique, and of course maximal left ideals always exist in a ring with identity.

So in fact, beyond being *local* the left ideals actually form a chain, a much stronger property.